# Horizontal two row menu doesn't work in Android

Tags: android, css, menu

My horizontal menu does work good on my computer, on iPhone but it does not work good on my Android phone.

The menu has to have two rows when the browser size is small. On my Android phone it shows only 1 row with two lines on top of each other.
BUT when I refresh the page on my phone, the menu appears the right way!

Does anyone know what's wrong?

This is the website http://nederlandoverzicht.nl/cs

This is my CSS code for the menu

```
#menu ul{list-style-type:none;
width: 90%;
margin: 0px auto;
display: table;
table-layout: fixed; /* the magic dust that ensures equal width */
text-align:center;
}

#menu ul li{
display: block;
width:33.3333333334%;
color:#fff;
padding-top:10px;
font-size:12px;
float:left;
font-family:"Tahoma";}

#menu{background-color:#bd4545;
border-radius: 5px;
height:58px;
width:100%;}
```

Comment: "position:center;" in not a valid CSS declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your current code, you have all of your `<li>` tags displaying as table-cell. No matter how wide you set them to be, the `<ul>` with `display:table;` is going to try to fit them all into it in a single row since they're not separated into containers set to display as table rows.

Depending on what solution you want to take, you could make them all `display:inline-block;` with a width of 16.6% normally, then use media queries to detect mobile devices and change the width to 33.3% to force the links into two rows of 3.